# How to Store the result of my MapReduce Job in a Hashmap and sorted it by value?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm new with HBase MapReduce job, I would like to compute the top 10 users on my table.

In my Reducer class, I put a local hashmap to store each result sorted map.

My question are:

How can I print out the content of my hashmap because add a 'System.out.println' statement doesn't work?

public class MyScanner2 {

```
static Configuration conf; 
static long startTimestamp;
static long stopTimestamp;
static Scan myScan;
static String tableToScan = "VStable";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    initScanner();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job = new Job(conf, "TOP10_users"); //TOP10_users is the name of the job
    job.setJarByClass(MyScanner2.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://zwinf5q45:8020/user/hdfs/top10users"));
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(Bytes.toBytes(tableToScan), myScan, Mapper1.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, IntWritable.class, job);
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("stats", Reducer1.class, job);
    //System.out.println(MyReducer.getMap().toString());
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}

public static void initScanner() throws IOException, ParseException{

    conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "hdfs://zwinf5q45:8020/apps/hbase/data");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zwinf5q46,zwinf5q44,zwinf5q43,zwinf5q42,zwinf5q41");
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");

    startTimestamp = convertToTimestamp("2014-05-21");
    stopTimestamp = convertToTimestamp("2014-05-22");;

    myScan = new Scan();
    myScan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(startTimestamp));
    myScan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(stopTimestamp));
    myScan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("infos"), Bytes.toBytes("bucketID"));
    myScan.setCaching(1000);



}

 public static long convertToTimestamp(String str_date) throws ParseException{

     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(str_date);
     java.sql.Timestamp timestamp= new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());

     return timestamp.getTime();
}
```

}

class Mapper1 extends TableMapper {

```
private int numRecords = 0;
private static final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

@Override
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result values, Context context) throws IOException {

    // extract resource
    if (values.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The scanner is empty");
    }
    else{

        ImmutableBytesWritable resource = new ImmutableBytesWritable(values.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("infos"), Bytes.toBytes("bucketID")));

        try {
            context.write(resource, one);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        numRecords++;
        if ((numRecords % 10000) == 0) {
            context.setStatus("mapper processed " + numRecords + " records so far");
        }
    }


}
```

}

class Reducer1 extends TableReducer {

```
static HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

public void reduce(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    int sum = 0;

    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
    }        
    map.put(key.toString(),sum);
    System.out.println ("HashMap content" + Arrays.toString (map.values().toArray ()));

}
```

}

Comment: `HashMaps` are not guaranteed to have any particular order, nor is the order of their elements guaranteed to remain constant, so `HashMap` wouldn't be the right map to use if you want your results to be sorted.

Comment: How about using a SortedMap

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `doesn't work`? `HashMap` should have a proper `toString()` method...

Comment: What should I use instead of HashMap? Or do you have any idea on how I could add some process befoe trying to print the content of my 'HashMap' or whatever? thanks

Comment: As @IwishIcouldthinkofagood said, if you want a sorted map, using one of `SortedMap`'s implementations (`TreeMap` or `ConcurrentSkipListMap`) is a better idea

Comment: About doesn't work? When I try my code it doesn't print anything although the hashmap is not empty?

Comment: That's rather odd... even an empty `HashMap` should at least print `{}`. If you put a different `println()` call in front of your existing one does that one print?

Comment: It doesn't work. but when I add some statements to write data in my HBase table, it's work. Please do you know some articles I can refer to?

Comment: So *no* `System.out.println()` calls work? You're saying calls to write data to a table work, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: yes, no System.out.println() calls work. I add all my code in order to let you see if the problem is not somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

As to why your output is wrong try

```
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (map.values().toArray ()));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the proper way is to output the result of reducer to files/HBase tables using `context.write()`.

If you want to use `println()` to print output, you can still view them using the MapReduce web console (usually located at `http://localhost:50030`). Choose a job, go to its completed reduce tasks -> pick a task -> check "Task Logs". Please note that each reducer will create its own stdout in Task Logs, so you may need to check result for all reducers.